# instagram api OAuthPermissionsException live mode

Tags: api, permissions, instagram

I'm having an issues with the new API policy of Instagram
I already got my app approved and got basic permissions

[IG API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HB7F.jpg)

When using the app on sandbox mode I can get API response only for my own user, however when I move to Live Mode and try using the API all I receive is error 400 code

For example
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?access_token=MY-TOKEN&count=6&q=world

**Response**

```
{
  meta: {
    error_type: "OAuthPermissionsException",
    code: 400,
    error_message: "This client has not been approved to access this resource."
  }
}
```

Even using the same API with my own username still getting the same error

I was trying to search on it but all I can find is the same error happens to unauthorized users

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed the `This client has not been approved to access this resource` Issue by Authorizing the Instagram `public_content` scope by visiting the following URL and clicking Authorize.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[YOUR_REDIRECT_URI]&scope=public_content&response_type=token
```

Comment: Tried this as of today (4/6/2017) and got the following error: `{"error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "code": 403, "error_message": "Implicit authentication is disabled"}`

Comment: Same problem as the previous comment here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @user3684314 , to stop the "Implicit authentication is disabled" message you need to go to https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ , manage your client,  switch to the **Security** tab, and untick **Disable implicit OAuth**

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, I can't use that endpoint because I have only permission for basic. for more information https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same problem and I changed my endpoint to basic permission but I still can't get any data, even my own.